# Communicate with QThreads

Tags: multithreading, qt, pyqt, qthread

Right now (just for the explanation's sake) The Main.process() function and the WorkerThread.run() function are the same.
They operate by getting a value from the listWidget what is on the Main layout.
I would like my workerthread class to use the parameter I set on the main list widget.

```
import sys, time
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Main, self).__init__()

        self.trdprocessbtn = QPushButton("Thread Processing")
        self.guiprocessbtn = QPushButton("Main Processing")

        self.listwidget = QListWidget()
        for i in range(10):
            self.listwidget.addItem(str(i))

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.listwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.guiprocessbtn)
        layout.addWidget(self.trdprocessbtn)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.guiprocessbtn.clicked.connect(self.process)

        self.workerthread = WorkerThread()
        self.trdprocessbtn.clicked.connect(self.startthread)

    def startthread(self):
        self.workerthread.start()

    def process(self):
        x = self.listwidget.currentItem().text()
        for i in range(int(x)):
            print "this is main processing ", i 
            time.sleep(1)

    def dialogOpen(self):
        dialog = Dialog()
        dialog.exec_()

class WorkerThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(WorkerThread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        x = self.listwidget.currentItem().text()
        for i in range(int(x)):
            print "This is thread processing ", i 
            time.sleep(1) 


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Main()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: You need to add more information. What have you tried? Show an example.

Comment: You can start by reading "How to Really, Truly use QThread: http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

Comment: Probably a better link is: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/thread-basics.html (I really do not like linking blogs like the given or "you are wrong"-QThread posts) There are valid reasons for all implementations. The official docs give a good advice here

Answer (score 1):

Your line `x = self.listwidget.currentItem().text()` in `run` method is bad. You are allowed to access widgets only from main/GUI thread.

Another thing is, your `process` slot blocks! Never block the main thread (and if you block another thread, you might be doing it wrong if you're not sure you're doing it right).

A short list of fixes:

- Remove the thread's `run` method and let the Qt event loop run in the thread, too.
- Connect `QListWidget::currentTextChanged(const QString & currentText)` signal to a new slot in your thread and in your main class, then make that slot start/update the timer and counter mentioned next.
- Replace your blocking loops with use of `QTimer`, connect the `timeout` signal to a slot which does what you now do in a loop. Since you sleep for 1 second, you should set the timer to go off once per second. Since you want to run only some set number of times, add counter variables to your classes, and keep track of how many times the timeout has happened, and turn the timer off when finished.
- If you need more complex list data processing, then create a slot for this in your main class, connect appropriate `QListWidget` signal to it. Then add a signal to main class with processed data for the thread, which you will emit from this slot. Finally, add matching slot for the thread to handle the data sent by your own signal, in the thread. You need to do this, because (I think) accessing just the data of QListWidget is not thread safe either.

Comment: How can be seen a main gui defined signal in any other thread?

Comment: I don't know how to do it with *pyqt*, but signals and slots are a core concept in Qt. Here are links to Qt C++ docs for [Qt4](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) and [Qt5](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html), whichever you are using. That should get you started on the concept and allow you to search how to do it with *pyqt*.

Comment: @hoportyo And about signals and threads. Each *QObject* subclass instance has some thread affinity, and when you connect a signal to a slot of and object "living" in a different thread, then by default Qt will queue that signal in the target thread, and call the slot method in that thread. So connecting signals and slots between threads works right pretty much automatically, you don't need to worry about synchronization or do anything special, Qt does that for you (with default signal/slot connection type, and as long as you don't have for ex. global variables you access from many threads).

Comment: @hoportyo Hmm, and one more note: if you are unclear on such basic Qt concepts as signals&slots, you will have hard time trying to do multi-threaded code. Qt is event based, and you can do basically everything *without* threads: just never block the event loop, only react to the data or signal, then return from your code to Qt event loop, which will call your code again when it has something for your code to do.